# Parse -D VM Args in .bat file and call Java application

Tags: java, batch-file, jvm, args

I am starting my Java application with a bat file. To call the application I use VM Args and normal Args. The problem is that this code only takes `-Dcom.xxx.fortify.fpr.excel.cell.filterMapping` as VM Arg and `"C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\filterMappings.properties"` is added to the `USER_OPTS` variable.

My VM Argument:

```
-Dcom.xxx.fortify.fpr.excel.cell.filterMapping="C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\filterMappings.properties"
```

My attempt to parse -D VM Args:

```
:: Parse out the Java args that start with -X or -D
set USER_VM_OPTS=
set USER_OPTS=
shift
:moreargs
if x%0x == xx goto donewithargs
set arg=%0
set argnq=%arg:"=%
if %argnq:~0,2% == -X goto uservmargs
if %argnq:~0,2% == -D goto uservmargs
set USER_OPTS=%USER_OPTS% %arg%
goto skipvmargs
:uservmargs
set USER_VM_OPTS=%USER_VM_OPTS% %arg%
:skipvmargs
shift
goto moreargs
:donewithargs

echo USER_VM_OPTS: %USER_VM_OPTS%
echo USER_OPTS:    %USER_OPTS%

java %USER_VM_OPTS% -cp %CP%  com.xxx.xxx.Main %USER_OPTS%
```

Can anyone help me to fix this?

Comment: Start with a simple batch script containing this line only: `@echo * %* & @echo 0 %0 & @echo 1 %1 & @echo 2 %2 & @echo 3 %3` (or you can substitute `&` ampersand symbol with a _new line_). Call this script with your parameters to see how the supplied arguments are processed. E.g. `%0` is always name of the script own... [Read more...](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)

Comment: Instead of `if %argnq:~0,2% == -X` try `if /I "%argnq:~0,2%"=="-X"` and analogously for `if /I "%argnq:~0,2%"=="-D"`. However, there's no `-X` in your example of parameters supplied... And forget my previous comment on `%0`, had overlooked initial `shift`

Comment: `USER_VM_OPTS:  -Dcom.xxx.xxx.xxx.excel.cell.filterMapping
USER_OPTS:     "C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\filterMappings.properties"`

Comment: Please update your question and add _whole_ right `java` call how should be derived from your `batch.bat` arguments (not as displayed `java %USER_VM_OPTS%...` but instantiated, e.g. If `batch.bat -Daaa=bbb -Xccc=ddd eee` then `java -Xccc=ddd -cp eee -Daaa=bbb`)